# Meaning of $C([0,T], L^2(\Omega))$

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

In a course of partial differential equations I encounter:
$$f(\mathbf{x},t) \in C([0,T], L^2(\Omega)).$$

Does $C([0,T], L^2(\Omega)) = \{f(\mathbf{x},t)\in L^2(\Omega): \forall t \in [0,T]\}$?

But what is the meaning of the $C$? I see the notation 
$$f(\mathbf{x},t) \in L^2({]0,T[}, L^2(\Omega))$$
appearing as wel.

Comment: You are dealing with Bochner-spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space

Comment: The $C(...)$ is just the normal continous function space definition from the metric space $([0,T],|\cdot|)$ into the metric space $(L^2(\Omega),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)})$. EDIT: I cannot edit my comment above anymore. I just want to add 2 more links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a Banach space, $1 \leq p < \infty$. We define

$$ L^p(a,b,V)=\{[u]~|~u:[a,b]\to V \text{ is Bochner measurable and satsfies } \int_a^b ||u(t)||^p_{V} dt<\infty \}$$

where Bochner measurable means that there exists a sequence of simple functions $u_n:[a,b]\to V$ such that $u_n(t) \to u(t)$ for $n \to \infty$ for almost all $t \in [a,b]$. This space is a Banach space with the norm $||u||:=\left( \int_a^b ||u(t)||^p_{L^p(V)} dt \right)^{1/p}$.

And to go back to your first question we define

$$C([a,b],V)=\{u ~|~ u:[a,b] \to V \text{ continuous} \}$$

and this is a Banach space with the norm $||u||:=\max_{t \in [a,b]} ||u(t)||_V$. It has some nice properties, for example it can be identified with a closed subspace of the Banach space
$$ L^\infty(a,b,V)=\{[u]~|~u:[a,b]\to V \text{ is Bochner measurable and } \text{ess sup}_{t \in [a,b]} ||u(t)||_V<\infty \text{ holds}\}.$$

For further theory you can have a look at 'Evans: Partial Differential Equations' and 'Wloka: Partial Differential Equations' that have both a great introduction to this topic with several applications to PDEs.

To apply this to your special case we have

$$C([0,T], L^2(\Omega))=\{u ~|~ u:[0,T] \to L^2(\Omega) \text{ continuous} \}$$ so your intuition was quite good but we have additionally continuity.